# Data getting overwritten or corrupted. What is the reason?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

Here is my code for the controller and the service. I am using AngularJS v1.6

```
app.controller('ServicesCtrl',['$scope','$http','DataService',function($scope,$http,DataService){

 $scope.returnedData = DataService.GetData('services1.json'); 
}]);

app.controller('ContactCtrl',['$scope','$http','DataService',function($scope,$http,DataService){

 $scope.returnedData = DataService.GetData('location.json'); 
// console.log($scope.returnedData);
}]);

app.service('DataService', ['$http', function($http){
 var data;
 this.GetData = function(path) {
   $http.get(path).then(function(response){
    //console.log(response.data);
   data = response.data;
  });
  return data;
 };
}]);
```

Why is my data getting corrupted on return to the controller function. I am getting an unexpected property of `$$hashkey` with the value of an object(`12`). I am a beginner so kindly explain in easy terms. I am able to log out the correct data inside the `DataService` but it gets corrupted inside the controller. The data of both the controller just gets mixed in the view. Even if I don't use one of the controller, the other one is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call like below: Promise will resolve and it will provide data in your controller. checkout working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:CR2TtS1zz9wFGgsl5z2c?p=preview)

```
app.controller('ServicesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'DataService', function($scope, $http, DataService) {

      DataService.GetData('services1.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.returnedData = response.data;
      });
    }]);

    app.controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'DataService', function($scope, $http, DataService) {

      DataService.GetData('location.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.returnedData = response.data;
      });
    }]);

    app.service('DataService', ['$http', function($http) {
      var data;
      this.GetData = function(path) {
        return $http.get(path)
      };
    }]);
```

Comment: Hi, good answer but I would still have to write almost the same amount of code in every controller for making that request for data to avoid which I created a service in the first place. Is there any better method/way to decrease the redundancy?